# What is the difference between DATA_TYPE and COLUMN_TYPE in MySql INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Isn't DATA_TYPE just a short version of COLUMN_TYPE?

Example:

COLUMN_TYPE: int(10) unsigned

DATA_TYPE: int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATA_TYPE` is part of the standard for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and thus shows a standard name for the data type.

`COLUMN_TYPE` is a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) specific extension to [this view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) and is here providing more, mysql specific, information about the data type.

Answer (score 0):

`COLUMN_TYPE` is a custom extension to the ANSI standard `DATA_TYPE` for that schema view and differs in that it includes the size of the type if one is available, E.g it returns `'varchar(size)'` whereas `DATA_TYPE` would simply return `'varchar'`.